# Get specific Inline CSS Style And Style Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to get specific inline css styles from an element, including the style name itself and the value.

I have an element that contains different inline styles like so.

```
<div style="background-color:red; display:block; background-size:cover; background-attachment:fixed; background-repeat:repeat-y; cursor:pointer; width:100%"></div>
```

I want to get the styles of that element(including the style name itself and value), but only the ones that have to do with "background" and ignore the others like "display, cursor, width"..etc

So to get the styles with jQuery I simply do this

```
$("div").attr("style");
```

That will return all the styles of the element including the ones I don't want. The solution I'm looking for would return something like this, which ignores the other styles that don't have to do with "background-"

```
background-color:red; background-size:cover; background-attachment:fixed; background-repeat:repeat-y;
```

I know I could get the individual styles like this

```
$("div").css("background");
$("div").css("background-size");
```

The problem with that is that it only gets the style value, and thats a problem because "background" could also be "background-image", or "background-repeat-y" could also be "background-repeat-x".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('div').each(function() {

style_arr=$(this).attr("style").split(';');
for(i=0;i<style_arr.length;i++) {
    if(style_arr[i].indexOf('background')!=-1) {
        console.log(style_arr[i]);
    }
}

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sx3psqvh/

Comment: This seems like a great solution, I will be adding the "background-" styles to a separate element, so how would I go about keeping the (semicolon)";" in the returned values?

Comment: If it is ok for your purpose, why not? :)

Comment: I think it would probably be more reliable to get the rules from the `style` object rather than relying on string manipulation, correct? This answer would break in situations that accessing the style object directly would not .

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister, i guess so... However, this should work too? If properties are inside style attribute (and they are), in HTML (inline styles), and OP use JQuery (and he uses it)... i don't see HUGE problem here....

Comment: @nevermind It should, in most cases. I just feel like my answer is more robust because it uses the browser's in-built parsing instead of doing string manipulation. My answer doesn't fail on any edge cases because all of the edge cases are already taken care of by the browser's parsing engine.

Comment: Ok, what should i do now? :) To be honest, i can't find 'edge cases' you've mentioned, except extremely bad-formatted inline styles, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rvobxosv/ Except this 'inline styling' make no sense at all - your solution doesn't work, too, or i might be wrong?

Comment: @nevermind For that specific example, your solution produces an invalid result, while mine produces a valid result for the style elements which are not malformed. I don't really want to get into an argument here about which solution is better, just that I have my reasons for believing that an object-based solution is more resilient to errors. And nothing personal - I don't think your solution is *wrong*. N.B. make sure you tag people with the `@` syntax so your messages hit their inbox.

Comment: I don't want to get in argument too, i am just interested for 'edge cases'... and i want to learn. Point is: bad inline styling -> no useful results, in both cases, proper inline styling (spaces included) -> useful results in both cases. :)

Answer (score 2):

String manipulation is the wrong tool for this job, and I'm surprised that the other answers use it. The style element was designed for this task.

You can find a list of all inline styles by looking at `element.style`. The object looks like this:

[image]

You can see it contains each of the inline CSS rules separate from one another. Here is a very short **live demo** that prints this object to the console so you can see what I mean:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("thediv");
console.log(el.style);
```

```html
<div id="thediv" style="background-color:red; display:block; background-size:cover; background-attachment:fixed; background-repeat:repeat-y; cursor:pointer; width:100%"></div>
```

The object contains both an iterable list of rules (so for instance `element.style[0]` is `background-color`), as well as a dictionary so that you can get at specific rules by name. You should then be able to easily filter this list to get any specific rules you're looking for.

---

Here is a **live demo** that shows you how you can get all of the rules with the string `background` in them (open up the console). It puts the results into an array of name and value pairs that's easy to access:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("thediv");

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < el.style.length; i++) {
    if (el.style[i].indexOf("background") !== -1) {
        result.push({name: el.style[i], value: el.style[el.style[i]]});
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="thediv" style="background-color:red; display:block; background-size:cover; background-attachment:fixed; background-repeat:repeat-y; cursor:pointer; width:100%"></div>
```

Comment: The other solutions work, but this one disregards any errant spaces in the inline style, which is nice.  For the solutions using string manipulation, if you have an inline style like `background-color     :    red      ;`, then you'll probably want to `.trim()` things.

Comment: Is this one of possible edge cases you've mentioned? http://jsfiddle.net/rvobxosv/ I am not sure that in (absurd) cases like this anything could work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var filteredStyles = $.grep($("div").attr("style").split(';'), function(style) {
        return style.indexOf("background") > -1;
    });
    console.log(filteredStyles);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6he3hu6y/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
var style = $("div").attr("style");
var arrayStyle = style.split(';');
var backgroundStyles = '';
for (i = 0; i < arrayStyle.length; ++i) {
    if (arrayStyle[i].indexOf("background") >= 0) {
        backgroundStyles+=arrayStyle[i]+';';
    }
}   
console.log(backgroundStyles);
```

First of all, you get the whole style attribute, 
then include all the CSS attributes splitting by the ";" into an array and finally for each key of the array looking for values containing "background". If so, just concat that value to a variable, adding ';' at the end of each value.